# Updating chart title according to zoom/pan

Tags: dygraphs

I am trying to update the dygraph title according to the current visible window. Such information can be retrieved using graph.xAxisRange(), however checking the documentation shows that there is only a callback for zoom.

The zoom callback works fine but won't get called after a pan is made. Also tried to use draw callback with lack of success.

Is there any possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawCallback` is what you want. You have to be careful to avoid loops with it, though — calling `updateOptions` inside of a `drawCallback` can invoke the `drawCallback` again. Take a look at [`synchronizer.js`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/cf4a09a9048ae6089f67c32c6d9ae55a8458873f/src/extras/synchronizer.js#L155) to see a workaround.

An alternative would be to throttle your calls to `updateOptions` within the `drawCallback`, e.g. to one update every 500ms.

Comment: After I wrote the question I was trying to solve it on my own, my idea consists in wrapping the endPan and creating a callback to handle it

`var temp = Dygraph.endPan;
var callback = function(event, g, context) { g.updateOptions({title: 'update title here'}); };
Dygraph.endPan = function(event, g, context) { temp(event, g, context); callback(event, g, context); };`

However, that will not update the chart title properly. Keeping some old lines there, chart.resize() won't trigger a full redrawn because the div size is still the same I guess.

https://i.imgur.com/K97GZJJ.png

Comment: That would remove the need to throttle or to deal with drawCallback at all.