# Redraw range selector or graph title after show

Tags: javascript, dygraphs, redraw

When I programatically show title or hide/show range selector after the graph is created the old axis lines stays there.

[image: Title with bad axis lines]

The same problem mentioned @leomoty in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764367/updating-chart-title-according-to-zoom-pan#comment53373968_32767061) comment.

The `graph.resize()` function does not help. Only resizing the browser window.

Dygraph version 1.1.1

Comment: You can't enable/disable the range selector after creating a chart. See [this issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/360).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a bit late, but here's the solution.

```
// kill rangeselector object (this is not cleared by dygraph)
delete dchart.rangeSelector_;
// update
dchart.updateOptions({ 
    // showRangeSelector: FULLVERSION,
    // or whatever settings you want
});
// resize so redraw is forced
// instead of #chart put #whatever-your-div-id-is
var cur_width = $("#chart").width();
var cur_height = $("#chart").height();
// instead of dchart put the variable name of your chart
// in a lot of the examples this is g
dchart.resize(10, 10);
dchart.resize(cur_width, cur_height);
```

This solution is an adaptation of the hack found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CGYFd/3/).  I have edited it to include more documentation/explanation and to work with auto-set heights and widths rather than just hard-coded ones.